# php is not updating my database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have this php page, which suppose to display an image and then update "download" row in database with 1 number for each visit, some times this works , and for some other pictures it's not working, how can i fix this ? please take a look at my code if there's something wrong :

```
<?php

include 'conf_global.php';

if ($_GET['id'])
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}
else
{
    die ("no id selected");
}

@ $db = mysql_pconnect($mysql['host'], $mysql['user'], $mysql['pass']) or die(mysql_error());
//IT"S NOT WORKING!
if (!$db)
{
    die("error");
}
mysql_select_db($mysql['db']) or die(mysql_error());

$query = "SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE id='" . $id ."'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if (!$result)
{
    die("MySQL Select error");
}

$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num_results ==0)
{
die("Image not found");
}

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if ($id != 0)
{
    $downloads = $row['downloads'] + 1;

    $lastuse = time();

     $ss = mysql_query("select downloads from `images` where id='".$id."'") or die(mysql_error());
     $rr = mysql_fetch_array($ss);

    $query = "update `images` set downloads='".($rr['downloads']+1)."' where id='".$id."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result)
    {
        die("MySQL update error");
    }

    $query = "UPDATE `images` SET lastuse='" . $lastuse . "' WHERE id='". $id ."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result)
    {
        die("MySQL update error2");
    }

    //get current stats
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `stat_cache`";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if (!$result)
    {
        die("MySQL Select error");
    }
    $stat = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    //band update
    $bandwidth = $stat['band'] + $row['size'];
    $query = "UPDATE `stat_cache` SET band='" . $bandwidth . "' WHERE 1";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result)
    {
        die("MySQL Update error");
    }

    //downloads update
    $downloads = $stat['downloads'] + 1;
    $query = "UPDATE `stat_cache` SET downloads='" . $downloads . "' WHERE 1";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result)
    {
        die("MySQL Update error");
    }
}
//Lets create the image, now.
if(!file_exists('./uploads/' . $id)) {
    die("Image not found");
    exit;
}
header('Content-type: ' . $row['type']);

$fp = fopen('./uploads/' . $id, 'r');

$contents = fread($fp, $maxfilesize);
fclose($fp);

echo $contents;

?>
```

Comment: Well when it doesn't work, what error message are you seeing?

Comment: Mayby is $rr['downloads'] an string, and then you need to convert it to an int... What does it says when you do this:
echo $rr['downloads'] . '<br />'.($rr['downloads'] + 1);

Comment: Do the whole thing as an transaction and set the isolation level so that you see uncommited changes to get the right number in the case of multiple uses. Also you can upadte last_use and downloads at the same time. I think your index is breaking when it is not working cos of multiuse

Comment: @moopet it show me no error, it just not update the value at the database row

Comment: @Jester thank you for the advise, altho it works for some pictures, but i will try your way.

Comment: thank you @TWCrap , i can't see what it say because as you can see it return as an Image not php page.

Comment: @Alamri Alright, mayby you want the do something like this: 
`$query = "update `images` set downloads='".intval(($rr['downloads']+1))."' where id='".$id."'";`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this its working :) you add wrong code

```
<?php

include 'conf_global.php';

if ($_GET['id'])
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}
else
{
    die ("no id selected");
}

@ $db = mysql_pconnect($mysql['host'], $mysql['user'], $mysql['pass']) or die(mysql_error());
//IT"S NOT WORKING!
if (!$db)
{
    die("error");
}
mysql_select_db($mysql['db']) or die(mysql_error());

$query = "SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE id='" . $id ."'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if (!$result)
{
    die("MySQL Select error");
}

$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num_results ==0)
{
die("Image not found");
}
else {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $downloads = $row['downloads'] + 1;

    $lastuse = time();

     $ss = mysql_query("select downloads from `images` where id='".$id."'") or die(mysql_error());
     $rr = mysql_fetch_array($ss);

    $query = "update `images` set downloads='".($rr['downloads']+1)."' where id='".$id."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result)
    {
        die("MySQL update error");
    }

    $query = "UPDATE `images` SET lastuse='" . $lastuse . "' WHERE id='". $id ."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result)
    {
        die("MySQL update error2");
    }

    //get current stats
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `stat_cache`";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if (!$result)
    {
        die("MySQL Select error");
    }
    $stat = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    //band update
    $bandwidth = $stat['band'] + $row['size'];
    $query = "UPDATE `stat_cache` SET band='" . $bandwidth . "' WHERE 1";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result)
    {
        die("MySQL Update error");
    }

    //downloads update
    $downloads = $stat['downloads'] + 1;
    $query = "UPDATE `stat_cache` SET downloads='" . $downloads . "' WHERE 1";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result)
    {
        die("MySQL Update error");
    }
}
//Lets create the image, now.
if(!file_exists('./uploads/' . $id)) {
    die("Image not found");
    exit;
}
header('Content-type: ' . $row['type']);

$fp = fopen('./uploads/' . $id, 'r');

$contents = fread($fp, $maxfilesize);
fclose($fp);

echo $contents;

?>
```

Comment: thank you , it works, i think i forgot to remove "if ($id != 0)"

Answer (score 3):

If two clients download the same image at the same time, they may overlap in reading and updating the table. They'll both read the same value in the SELECT query, add 1 to it, and then UPDATE with the same new value.

Instead of adding 1 in PHP, let the database do it itself:

```
$query = "update `images` set downloads=downloads+1, lastuse='" . $lastuse . "' where id='".$id."'";
```

It's possible to solve this problem entirely in the client by using locks and transactions, but in this case it's simpler to just do it in one query.

Also, you should not use the mysql_* functions in new code, they have been deprecated. Please switch to mysqli_* or PDO, and use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: I'm still a beginner but will try to follow your instructions,i hope i could fix this and avoid the security hole, thank you

Comment: you code worked well instead the old one, but still the same issue. it only update the value for some pictures. others are not.

Answer (score 2):

1. use of mysql_* functions is deprecated. Rewrite your code with [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli)
   or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo).
2. What does mysql_error say?
3. Following code is unreachable:

.

```
$db = mysql_pconnect($mysql['host'], $mysql['user'], $mysql['pass']) or die(mysql_error());

//You never come here is mysql_pconnect failed because already called die();

//IT"S NOT WORKING!

if (!$db)
{
    die("error");
}
```

Comment: plus , mysql is not showing any errorm because my code work with some picture. and for pictures that not working with, it show me no error, it just not update the value in DB